# Does Spock have Test Event Listeners

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

Does spock has any Test event listener like how TestNg has `ITestListener`. ?

So that I can have access, when the test cases failed etc.

Comment: I've never seen any listener in spock.

Comment: Mention your purpose to do that

Comment: Spock does have this feature and I answered this in another thread here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39529552/1053487 Check if that helps

Answer (score 7):

Spock does have listeners. Unfortunately the official documentation, which is otherwise excellent, has "TODO" under *Writing Custom Extensions*: http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/extensions.html.

**Update:** The official docs have been updated to include helpful information about custom extensions: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/extensions.html. See those for more details.

There are two ways: **Annotation-based** and **Global**.

**Annotation-based**

Three pieces here: the annotation, the extension, and the listener.

The annotation:

```java
    import java.lang.annotation.*
    import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])
    @ExtensionAnnotation(ListenForErrorsExtension)
    @interface ListenForErrors {}
```

The extension (Updated):

```java
    import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension
    import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo

    class ListenForErrorsExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<ListenForErrors> {
        void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
            spec.addListener(new ListenForErrorsListener())
        }

       @Override
       void visitSpecAnnotation(ListenForErrors annotation, SpecInfo spec){
        println "do whatever you need here if you do. This method will throw an error unless you override it"
    }
    }
```

The listener:

```java
    import org.spockframework.runtime.AbstractRunListener
    import org.spockframework.runtime.model.ErrorInfo

    class ListenForErrorsListener extends AbstractRunListener {
        void error(ErrorInfo error) {
            println "Test failed: ${error.method.name}"
            // Do other handling here
        }
    }
```

You can then use your new annotation on a Spec class or method:

```java
    @ListenForErrors
    class MySpec extends Specification {
        ...
    }
```

**Global**

This also has three pieces: the extension, the listener, and the registration.

```java
    class ListenForErrorsExtension implements IGlobalExtension {
        void visitSpec(SpecInfo specInfo) {
            specInfo.addListener(new ListenForErrorsListener())
        }
    }
```

You can use the same `ListenForErrorsListener` class as above.

To register the extension, create a file named `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` in the `META-INF/services` directory. If using Gradle/Maven, this will be under `src/test/resources`. This file should contain only the fully qualified class name of your global extension, for example:

```
com.example.tests.ListenForErrorsExtension
```

**References**

For examples, see the Spock built-in extensions here:
https://github.com/spockframework/spock/tree/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/lang
https://github.com/spockframework/spock/tree/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/extension/builtin

Comment: Hi, I do everything like described in "Annotation-based" section but when I execute my annotated specification I get such exception: "org.spockframework.runtime.InvalidSpecException: @ListenForErrors may not be applied to Specs".

Answer (score 0):

Spock has interaction listening via Mock:

```
def "should send messages to all subscribers"() {
    given:
    def subscriber = Mock(Subscriber)

    when:
    publisher.send("hello")

    then:
    1 * subscriber.receive("hello")
}
```

See the [interaction based testing](http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#interactions) in the docs