# Execute code in Spock on test Succeed and Failure

Tags: spock, junit-rule

I want to execute a block of code that changes based on a pass or a fail. Basically looking to set the results from a test in our test case tracking software. I created my own test rules, shown below, but no matter if the test passes or fails it always just calls succeeded.

```
public class TestRules extends TestWatcher {

@Override
public void succeeded(Description description){
    log.error("This should only be called when passing");
}

@Override
public void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
    log.error("This Should only be called when Failing");
}
```

}

I set the rule in the test as follows

```
@Rule
public TestRules testRules = new TestRules()
```

I am hoping I am just missing something stupid and simple.

Comment: Hi Mouse, welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you get any error messages while executing this code?

Comment: Yes, its possible via extensions of spock. The really good usage example has been given here, so you can create a listener that would be called by spock on error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967241/does-spock-have-test-event-listeners

Comment: @StefanN no errors, but no matter if the test fails or passes it just ignores the failed rule.

Comment: @MarkBramnik Thanks, I have never used any of those but I will try to follow that as an outline and see if I can get it working.